# WPF UserControl property change not updating

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl that I add to my main application.
That UserControl contains a button for a UIElement

The UserControl contains a DispatchTimer and every 2 seconds based on some int values determines what the button image will be.

One of the methods called in the UserControl should set it's image but the control never displays the image that it was changed to.

```
public void SetNormal()
    {
        btnFlashAlert.Content = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/FlashButton.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Is there something i'm missing to get the look of the control update on the main application?

When I look at what .Content contains, it is correct. The UI doesn't reflect the change.

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="SC.FlashSystem.MainButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="53" Width="164">
<Button x:Name="btnFlashAlert" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Cursor="Hand" Click="btnFlashAlert_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="Images/FlashButton.png"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Codebehind ***Updated***

```
        public partial class MainButton : UserControl
{
    private SupportConsoleWeb.MessageData messageCounts { get; set; }
    private readonly DispatcherTimer flashButtonChangeTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private BitmapImage NormalImage { get; set; }
    private BitmapImage CriticalImage { get; set; }
    private BitmapImage AlertImage { get; set; }
    private BitmapImage InfoImage { get; set; }

    public MainButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        messageCounts = new SupportConsoleWeb.MessageData();
        messageCounts.CriticalCount = 0;
        messageCounts.AlertCount = 0;
        messageCounts.InfoCount = 0;

        NormalImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/FlashButton.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        CriticalImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/FlashButtonRed.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        AlertImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/FlashButtonOrange.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        InfoImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/FlashButtonGreen.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        flashButtonChangeTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        flashButtonChangeTimer.Tick += flashButtonChangeTimer_Tick;
        flashButtonChangeTimer.Start();
    }

    void flashButtonChangeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnFlashAlert.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if (btnFlashAlert.Content == null)
            {
                SetNormal();
            }
            else if (messageCounts.CriticalCount > 0 && btnFlashAlert.Content.Equals(CriticalImage))
            {
                SetNormal();
            }
            else if (messageCounts.AlertCount > 0 && btnFlashAlert.Content.Equals(AlertImage))
            {
                SetNormal();
            }
            else if (messageCounts.InfoCount > 0 && btnFlashAlert.Content.Equals(InfoImage))
            {
                SetNormal();
            }
            else if (messageCounts.CriticalCount > 0)
            {
                SetCritical();
            }
            else if (messageCounts.AlertCount > 0)
            {
                SetAlert();
            }
            else if (messageCounts.InfoCount > 0)
            {
                SetInfo();
            }
        }));
    }

    public void UpdateMessageCounts(SupportConsoleWeb.MessageData messageCounts)
    {
        this.messageCounts = messageCounts;
    }

    private void btnFlashAlert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        window.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void SetMessageCount(int criticalCount, int alertCount, int infoCount)
    {
        messageCounts.CriticalCount = criticalCount;
        messageCounts.AlertCount = alertCount;
        messageCounts.InfoCount = infoCount;
    }

    private void SetNormal()
    {
        btnFlashAlert.Content = NormalImage;
    }

    private void SetCritical()
    {
        btnFlashAlert.Content = CriticalImage;
    }

    private void SetAlert()
    {
        btnFlashAlert.Content = AlertImage;
    }

    private void SetInfo()
    {
        btnFlashAlert.Content = InfoImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your full XAML and code.

Comment: Your XAML is wrong, but also you're changing the `Button.Content` and putting the **same image** again, even if it worked you would not see any change visually. Please clarify this. Are you ever changing that to something else?

Comment: I'll post the code behind that was just one Method I posted

Comment: remove button template from xaml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your XAML To this

```
 <Image Source="{Binding TheImage}"/>
```

Add notify property changed

```
 public partial class MainButton : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Create the OnPropertyChanged Event

```
    void OnPropertyChanged(String prop)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Create a Bitmap prop and notify the prop changed event

```
    private BitmapImage _TheImage;

    public BitmapImage TheImage
    {
        get { return _TheImage; }
        set { _TheImage = value; OnPropertyChanged("TheImage"); }
    }
```

In your initializer

```
  public MainButton()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        TheImage = new BitmapImage();
```

Now in your setting methods call

```
TheImage = //Your Bitmap Goes here
```

I know this seems excessive but you will see it is a much cleaner implementation in the long run.

Comment: Perfect, this also cleaned up other parts of the logic

Comment: I was a skeptic for the longest. However, databinding is the only way to roll when doing WPF or variations there of.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its an issue with picture selection logic not having a default image when none of the conditions are met...

With that said, *IMHO* the picture logic would be better expressed by having all images pre-loaded and their visibility initially set to hidden. Then bind the visibility of each image to a specific *flag* boolean on the VM. Which the timer event can simply turn on or off the boolean(s) which will ultimately show or hide images as needed.

That removes any latency due to loading and showing of images for they will be pre-loaded; also it will solve any possible future memory issues due to loading/unloading of images.

### Example

The following example has a button with two images. Both image's visibility is bound to Booleans on the VM. The VM has one Boolean which the imageas work off of and a timer which changes its status every two seconds switching the images.

Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter  x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Button x:Name="bStatus" Width="48" Height="48">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Image Source="Images\Copy-icon.png" Visibility="{Binding IsCopyOn, 
                                                            Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Image Source="Images\Recycle-icon.png"
                Visibility="{Binding IsRecycleOn, 
                            Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

VM

```
public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _bSwitch;
    private readonly DispatcherTimer flashButtonChangeTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public bool IsRecycleOn
    {
        get { return _bSwitch; }

    }

    public bool IsCopyOn
    {
        get { return !_bSwitch; }
    }

    public MainVM()
    {
        flashButtonChangeTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        flashButtonChangeTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            _bSwitch = ! _bSwitch;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsCopyOn");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsRecycleOn");
        };
        flashButtonChangeTimer.Start();

    }

    /// <summary>Event raised when a property changes.</summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>Raises the PropertyChanged event.</summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property that has changed.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you gave me a few things to think about that I didn't register before with latency and memory issues. Could you show an example with binding multiple images to the button? Didn't think you can have more than one Image Source.